# Installing ExtJS

Tags: javascript, apache, extjs

I am new to ExtJS. I tried installing it as per the steps [`given here.`](http://www.sencha.com/learn/getting-started-with-ext-js-4)

But I am getting one error while running this command.

```
   sencha create jsb -a http://localhost:8080/helloext/index.html -p app.jsb3
```

Error msg :

> C:\Program Files\Apache Software
>   Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs\helloext>`sencha create jsb -a` http://localhost:8080/helloext/index.html -p app.jsb3 'sencha' is not
>   recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or
>   batch file.

What is the problem ?

PS : I already done with the prior steps of installing Apache Server and unzipping ExtJS SDK.

Thanks.

Comment: Is `sencha` in your [environment path](http://geekswithblogs.net/renso/archive/2009/10/21/how-to-set-the-windows-path-in-windows-7.aspx)?

Comment: No, I couldn't see any step for including sencha in my env path on sencha.com ? How to set sencha in env path ?

Comment: Find where it's installed and add that to your PATH using the tutorial I posted in my first comment.

Comment: It would be where the executable `sencha` is

Comment: I couldn't find sencha.exe in my sdk which I downloaded

Comment: @rfausak : your comments were very helpful . thanks ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Windows is not finding the `sencha` executable.

Are you sure you downloaded the Sencha Tools SDK?  (Current version is 1.2.3beta).  The link from that tutorial shows a page with an obvious link to download the ExtJS library, and less obvious link for the Sencha SDK.  Try downloading and installing this [from here](http://www.sencha.com/products/sdk-tools/download/sencha-sdk-tools-1.2.3-beta/windows). Then see if typing "sencha" on the command line does something sensible.

Comment: thanks for the link. Mistakley, I downloaded the `http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/download/`

Answer (score 2):

I dont have time to reaad te tutorial but I will let you know how I get started using extjs. I download the library and extract the folder. Name the folder extjs. Then in my webroot or whatever you prefer I make a directory called lib and place extjs inside of it. Then when i create a html document I reference the library by using `<script type="text/javascript" src="/lib/extjs/ext-all.js></script>`. This is how you can call it up in order to use it. If you have a "app/js" file simply reference it after the example I gave you above so that it is loaded after the ext-all.js file.